# Can we incentivize flagging, so that more people can watch after the comments sections?

Tags: discussion

I have some "helpful" flags recently, but I notice that I don't earn any rep for having used my flags with good judgment, whereas I earn +2 when my edits of questions are approved.

Can we incentivize flagging, so that more people can watch after the comments sections?

Can we earn rep, say, +2, for each flag used that's considered "helpful"?

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [Correct Flagging Incentive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229427/294691).

Comment: You get extra flags when you have enough useful flags :) Some people like to brag they've unlocked all 100 :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think flagging is already promoted.

There are 3 badges for raising useful flags:

- Bronze (Citizen Patrol) for raising one flag
- Silver (Deputy) for having 80 helpful flags
- Gold (Marshal) for having 500 helpful flags.

Also, the more useful flags you have, the more flags you get. Some people do like to 'brag' that they've unlocked all 100 ;)

Answer (score 6):

Besides what @TinkeringBell said, flagging is an easy task while handling it is not. You just flag it, but moderators (and users with certain privileges from community) check the validity of your flag. It involves more users who put more effort in it than you.

You can find posts/comments for flagging across the sites without having their knowledge while reputation is assigned for the knowledge and the efforts you put in your posts.

From [Help Center](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation),

> Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you; **it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re talking about**.

You get new privileges allowing you to do more actions rather than just flagging as you gain reputation which is also a sign that community trusts you, that you have knowledge about the topic. You may earn the rep but you will not understand how to use those privileges. Everyone can flag (after getting 15 rep, of course), but it doesn't simply make you expert in the topic.

Editing also requires knowledge and efforts. That's why you're awarded rep for this. However, you will not get any more rep once you earn the editing privileges or 1000 rep from suggested edits.

I have raised over 100 flags on the sites where I have zero knowledge of the topic those sites focus but I do know which flags to raise (though, most of them are spams of course). If I get rep for those flags, I'd not be able to use my privileges at the best due to lack of subject expertise.